# Reading from text file using ifstream 

Tags: c++

I am trying to read from text file using ifstream object with extraction operator (>>) , and when I perform the following code , it is not reading at all !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

void outputLine( int account, const char *const name , double balance )
      {
         cout << left << setw( 10 ) << account << setw( 13 ) << name
            << setw( 7 ) << setprecision( 2 ) << right << balance << endl;
      } // end function outputLine


int main()
{
    ofstream outfile("client.txt",ios::out);
    if (!outfile)
    {
        cout << "the file is not opened .. " << endl ;
        exit(1);
    }
    int account;
    char name[30];
    double balance;
    while (cin >> account >> name >> balance)
    {
        outfile << account << ends << name << ends << balance << endl ;
        cout << "? " ;
    }
    outfile.close();

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open( "client.txt",ios::in);

     if ( !inFile )
     {
      cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
       exit( 1 );
     } // end if

     cout << left << setw( 10 ) << "Account" << setw( 13 )
       << "Name" << "Balance" << endl << fixed << showpoint;

    while (inFile >> account >> name >> balance )
    {
        outputLine( account, name, balance );
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Is there any error in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

What are those `ends` manipulators doing there? I would guess you should be outputing spaces instead. And the obvious way to debug this is to write the code that creates the output file only  and then see if it works by examining the output with a text editor.

Comment: `std::ends` is a Microsoft-specific manipulator that inserts the end of string character `'\0'` to the stream. It's old and unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not reading because it's probably not writing. You didn't specify what you inputted into the console window when it asked you for input,  but if you don't put in input in the format of

```
integer string double
```

then nothing will be written to the file because `cin<<` will try to get a certain type and fail because the data doesn't match the type it wants.